# Equal transformations on both indexed content and query content before a search is attempted

Tags: terminology, search, search-engine, text-processing, natural-language-processing

In search engine indexing, a body of text is often processed before it is indexed. A common example is stemming, were words are reduced to their root form (plurals are dropped, tense is normalized). Other examples are lemmatization, soundex transformation, casing, etc.

So, this sentence...

> My name is Bond, James Bond

...might be indexed as the following tokens.

- my
- name
- be
- bond
- jame
- bond

A basic principle of information retrieval is that this only works if you do the transformation on the query as well.

If I was to search for "James", it would not match because that token was transformed to "jame". My search can only reliably work if the exact same set of transformations take place on the query as well, so my query for "James" would be equally transformed into "jame" before any token matching was attempted.

(I liken this to algebra, where you have to do the same calculations on both sides of the equals sign.)

Is there a name for this principle of having to transform both indexed content and query content equally before attempt to compare them? I'm trying to explain this concept to some students, and it would be helpful if there was an existing term for it.

Comment: Some kind of normalization? Specific normalization techniques have individual names. This looks like [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). On a lower level, Unicode poses some fun challenges when comparing for equivalence. E.g. decomposing characters into a compatibility decomposition NFKD, or performing case-folding.

Comment: @amon yes exactly! it is without a doubt stemming, i.e. reducing words to their base form. However, the term “stemming” describes the transformation that is made to the raw data. The term does not designate the more general principle of applying the same transformation to the indexed data and to the search terms.

Answer (score 0):

There is no broadly used name for this technique since it is the normal way of searching and indexing:

- you store some data
- you use some keys that correspond to the data stored to find it back.

This is done everyday in a lot of systems, when passwords are hashed, and later stored or compared via their hashes.

In the domain of record management and archiving, the use of a standardised vocabulary (keywords) for categorizing content, and the use of normalised titles (e.g. with or without apostrophes and punctuation, skipping of leading articles, etc...) was independent and pre-existant to IT indexing : it is part of the usual (manual and now electronic) indexing practice.

If you are nevertheless looking for a term, you may consider “[normalisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))”: this term is used in statistics to make sure that the data stays in an expected range despite noise.  It is also used in database management, but not to deal with the data content but its structure (i.e. the dependency relations between the content). I heard many librarians in my geographic area using it for the standardization process they apply to document titles.

Another term to consider, which is perhaps more accurate in the domain of linguistics and NLP,  could be  “**[equivalence mapping]**[2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics))”: a [**mapping**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)) is a (generally unidirectional) transformation function; an a [**semantic equivalence**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_equivalence) represents something which is not identical but has a similar meaning.